# java.util.regex.Pattern for json

Tags: java, regex

my application uses java.util.regex.Pattern to allow user do regexMatch and regexReplace in json format.

sample json data as below:

```html
{
    "childId": "Facility/Hospital A/Building 1/Machine A",
    "name": "Machine A at Hospital A",
    "parentId": "Facility/Hospital A/Building 1"
}
```

if user wants to replcae the "parentId" value "Facility/Hospital A/Building 1"

to value "Facility/Hospital A/Building 1 New" , but not replace childId , is that possible?

the sample command as below:

```html
  "regexMatch" : "/Building 1",
  "regexReplace" : "/Building 1 New"
```

the expected outcome would be:

```html
{
    "childId": "Facility/Hospital A/Building 1/Machine A",
    "name": "Machine A at Hospital A",
    "parentId": "Facility/Hospital A/Building 1 New"
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using JSON-libraries, instead of regex. Seems like the better way to go about it.

Comment: `jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("    \"parentId\": \"Facility/Hospital A/Building 1\"\n", "    \"parentId\": \"Facility/Hospital A/Building 1 New\"\n");`

Comment: @DevilsHnd "regexMatch" : "(" \"parentId\": \"Facility/Hospital A/Building 1\"\n", " \"parentId\": \"Facility/Hospital A/Building 1 New\"\n")", POSTMAN error as in not valid json format?

Comment: i have tried this, not working as well.       "regexMatch" : "(?:\\\"parentId\\\":)(.*)",
      "regexReplace" :  "Facility/Hospital A New/Building 1"